# Angular 2 - typescript: Number attribute returns 0

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I have this JSON object. This object is an array

```js
export class viewItem {
    Id: number = 0;
    Euser_id: number = 0;
    Item_Id: number = 0;
    Item: viewItemContent;
    Permissions: number = 0;
    PinnedOn: number = 0;
    IsCopy: boolean = false;
    IsShare: boolean = false;
    References: number = 0;
    Span: number = 0;
    Row: number;
    Col: number;
    Config: string;
    UiMeta: string;
}
```

I access the object using the array filter like so

```js
let boardItem123: viewItem = this.boardviewItems.filter(bItem => bItem.Id === payload)[0];
```

And it shows the response as

```js
Col : 1
Euser_id : 8
Id : 227
IsCopy : false
IsShare : false
Item : Object
Item_Id : 221
Permissions : 10
PinnedOn : 226
References : 0
Row : 2
Span : 2
UiMeta : "{"sizex": 1, "sizey": 3, "row": 2, "col": 1, "maxCols": 2, "minCols": 2, "dragHandle":".drag-handle"}"
```

Now, when I try to print the number attributes Row and Col like so, it is returning zero always.

```js
let bIRow = boardItem123.Row;
let bICol = boardItem123.Col;
console.log(bIRow, boardItem123.Row);
//Print 0 0
console.log(bIRow.toString(), boardItem123.Row.toString());
//Print 0 0
console.log(bICol, boardItem123.Col);
//Print 0 0
console.log(bICol.toString(), boardItem123.Col.toString());
//Print 0 0
console.log(boardItem123.UiMeta);
//Prints the right value
```

What is the problem? Why wouldn't it return the right values?

Comment: you printed boardItem123 to get object response?

Comment: Have you tried this.boardviewItems.filter(bItem => bItem.Id === payload)[0].Row ??

Comment: Suraj Rao, yes, the same object as shown above.

Comment: Sachin Gaur, I have tried that and the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried other Number properties? All are zero. If no, I would suggest to give some default value to Row & Col properties.

Comment: That makes no sense. What do you mean "it shows the response as"? How does it show it?  Is that all your code? How do you create the instances? Please provide more info.